# proguard returned with error code 1 while exporting a signed application package

Tags: android

Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

```
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find superclass or interface javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
```

and here is the proguard config file
This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

# Optimizations: If you don't want to optimize, use the
    # proguard-android.txt configuration file instead of this one, which
    # turns off the optimization flags.  Adding optimization introduces
    # certain risks, since for example not all optimizations performed by
    # ProGuard works on all versions of Dalvik.  The following flags turn
    # off various optimizations known to have issues, but the list may not
    # be complete or up to date. (The "arithmetic" optimization can be
    # used if you are only targeting Android 2.0 or later.)  Make sure you
    # test thoroughly if you go this route.
    -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
    -optimizationpasses 5
    -allowaccessmodification
    -dontpreverify

```
# The remainder of this file is identical to the non-optimized version
# of the Proguard configuration file (except that the other file has
# flags to turn off optimization).

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class javax.jdo.** { *; }
-keep interface javax.jdo.** { *; }

-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.lowagie.text.pdf.**
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.**
-dontwarn com.dropbox.sync.**

#Added for SDS
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class android.widget.Toast
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class de.psdev.licensesdialog.** { *; }
-keep interface de.psdev.licensesdialog.** { *; }
-keep class com.googlecode.** { *; }
-keep interface com.googlecode.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.** { *; }
-keep interface org.simpleframework.xml.** { *; }

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.softxpert.sds.frontend.activities.RecommendUsFacebookActivity

-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

-keep class com.dropbox.ledger.** { *; }
-keep interface com.dropbox.ledger.** { *; }


#keep all classes that might be used in XML layouts
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.Fragment

#down warns for test package
 -dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
 -dontwarn org.htmlcleaner.*
 -dontwarn org.junit.*
 -dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.*
 -dontwarn javax.xml.stream.*
 -dontwarn javax.*
 -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.*
 -dontwarn javax.servlet.http.*
 -dontwarn org.opencv.*
 -dontwarn org.openid4java.**
 -dontwarn org.openid4java.message.*
 -dontwarn com.google.android.**
 -dontwarn android.support.v4.**
 -dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions
 #ACRA specifics
# we need line numbers in our stack traces otherwise they are pretty useless
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# ACRA needs "annotations" so add this... 
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

Comment: Which is your JDO entry in the config?

Answer (score 1):

In your project's `proguard-project.txt` file, you'll need to add the JAR file of the JDO classes you used. For example:

```
-injars libs/jdo-1.0.0.jar
```

Note: `jdo-1.0.0.jar` is just an example. You will need to substitute it with the actual name of the JDO JAR file under your project's `libs` directory.

Comment: Edit your post and include your project's Proguard config so I can see what you are doing. Note: Only add what is in `proguard-project.txt` file and nothing else.

Comment: @user3796830 The are 2 files in an android project directory: proguard-project.txt and proguard-google-api-client.txt. You should add the above line to the first one, as ChuongPham said.